# Log scale on y axis but data have negative values

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, axis

I am trying to create a boxplot with a log y axis as I have some very small values and then some much higher values which do not work well in a boxplot with a continuous y axis. However, I have negative values which obviously do not work with a log scale. I was wondering if there was a way around this so that I can display my data on a boxplot which is still easy to interpret but has a more appropriate scale on the y axis.

```
    p <- ggplot(data = Elstow.monthly.fluxes, aes(x = Month1, y = CH4.Flux)) + stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", linetype = 1, width = 0.5) + geom_boxplot() +
xlab(expression("Month")) + ylab(expression(~CH[4]~Flux~(µg~CH[4]~m^{-2}~d^{-1}))) +
scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-5000,40000,5000), limits = c(-5000,40000))+
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black")) + theme(axis.text.y = element_text(colour = 
"black")) +
theme(panel.background = element_rect("white", "black")) +
theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=0.5)) +
theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 12))+ theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 14))+ 
theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 15, b = 0, l = 0))) + 
theme(axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 15, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0))) +
geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype ="dashed", colour = "black")
```

[image: Current boxplot without log scale]

Comment: Remove outliers: just keep everything thats `abs(Elstow.monthly.fluxes$CH4.Flux) <= X`, where `X` can be `4e3`

Comment: I am reluctant to remove these values are they are not measurement errors as outliers in the traditional sense would likely be, they are valid measurements that happen to be a lot higher than the rest. Is there a solution which would mean I could keep these values?

Answer (score 4):

While you could indeed use the secondary axis to get the labels you want as Zhiqiang suggests, you could also use a transformation that fits your needs.

Consider the following skewed boxplots:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = rep(letters[1:2], each = 500),
  y = rlnorm(1000) - 2
)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Instead, you could use the pseudo-log transformation to visualise your data:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = scales::pseudo_log_trans())
```

[image]

Alternatively, you could make any transformation you want. I personally like the inverse hyperbolic sine transformation, which is very much like the pseudo-log:

```
asinh_trans <- scales::trans_new(
  "inverse_hyperbolic_sine",
  transform = function(x) {asinh(x)},
  inverse = function(x) {sinh(x)}
  )

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = asinh_trans)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this is helpful, however I am getting an error when I try to run this with my data. "Error in is.trans(x) : object 'scales' not found". Is this code correct? p<- ggplot(data = Elstow.monthly.fluxes, aes(x = Month1, y = CH4.Flux)) + stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", linetype = 1, width = 0.5) + geom_boxplot() +
  xlab(expression("Month")) + ylab(expression(~CH[4]~Flux~(µg~CH[4]~m^{-2}~d^{-1}))) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = scales:pseudo_log_trans())+...

Comment: Have you tried with two `:`? I.e. `trans = scales::pseudo_log_trans()` ?

Comment: I think it has worked but it seems to have changed all the values of my data so the boxplot does not look the same. Any ideas why this might have happened?

Comment: Boxplots are calculated on scale transformed data, so that might influence where the outlier cutoff is.

Answer (score 0):

I have a silly solution: trick the secondary axis to re-scale `y` axis. I do not have your data, just made up some numbers for the purpose of demonstration.

First convert `y` values as `logy = log(y + 5000)`. When generating the graph, transform the values back to the original scale. I borrow the second axis to display the values. I am pretty sure others may have more elegant ways to do this.

I was lazy for not trying to find the right way to remove the primary `y` axis tick labels, just used `breaks = c(0)`.

```
df<-data.frame(y = runif(33, min=-5000, max=40000), 
           x = rep(c("Aug", "Sep", "Oct"),33)) 
library(tidyverse)
df$logy = log(df$y+5000)

p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = logy)) + 
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", linetype = 1, width = 0.5) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  xlab(expression("Month")) + 
  ylab(expression(~CH[4]~Flux~(µg~CH[4]~m^{-2}~d^{-1}))) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~(exp(.) -5000), 
                                         breaks = c(-4000, 0, 5000, 10000, 20000, 40000)), 
                     breaks = c(0))+ 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black")) + 
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black")) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect("white", "black")) +
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=0.5)) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 12))+ 
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 14))+ 
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 15, b = 0, l = 0))) + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 15, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0))) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = log(5000), linetype ="dashed", colour = "black") 
p
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`coord_trans()` is applied after the statistics are calculated (unlike scale).  This can be combined with the `pseudo_log_trans` to cope with negatives.

```
library(plotly)
set.seed(1234)
dat <- data.frame(cond = factor(rep(c("A","B"), each=200)), rating = c(rnorm(200),rnorm(200, mean=500)))

pseudoLog <- scales::pseudo_log_trans(base = 10)
p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=cond, y=rating)) + geom_boxplot() + coord_trans(y=pseudoLog)
```

[image: Example of boxplot with negative values on a pseudo-log scale]